# Python: Splitting a string in a list

Tags: python, string, url, loops, split

I am having trouble splitting an '&' in a list of URL's. I know it is because I cannot split a list directly but I cannot figure out how to get around this error. I am open for any suggestions.

```
def nestForLoop():
    lines = open("URL_leftof_qm.txt", 'r').readlines()
    for l in lines:
        toke1 = l.split("?")
        toke2 = toke1.split("&")
        for t in toke2:
            with open("ampersand_right_split.txt".format(), 'a') as f:
                    f.write
    lines.close()

nestForLoop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Ignacio points out, you should not be doing this in the first place. But I'll explain where you're going wrong, and how to fix it:

toke2 is a list of two strings: the main URL before the ?, and the query string after the &. You don't want to split that list, or everything in that list; you just want to split the query string. So:

```
mainurl, query = l.split("?")
queryvars = query.split("&")
```

What if you *did* want to split everything in the first list? There are two different things that could mean, which are of course done differently. But both require a loop (explicit, or inside a list comprehension) over the first list. Either this:

```
tokens = [toke2.split("&") for toke2 in l.split("?")]
```

or

```
tokens = [token for toke2 in l.split("?")
          for token in toke2.split("&")]
```

Try them both out to see the different outputs, and hopefully you'll understand what they're doing.

Comment: I'm getting a Value error. Probably because there is code in my file that does not have an & on some lines. How can I fix this?

Comment: Having lines without a & wouldn't raise anything, but a line without a ? would. Change the first line to `mainurl, _, query = l.partition('?')`.

Comment: It splits on the '?' but not on the '&'.

Comment: @MichaelJerzyRegdosz: If you're actually using the code I wrote above, splitting on the `?` but not the `&` will not raise a `ValueError`; you'll successfully get a 1-element list in `queryvars`. So, either you're wrong, and it's the `?` that's missing, or you wrote different code than what I showed, in which case I can't debug code that I haven't seen.

Answer (score 8):

NO. STOP.

```
qs = urlparse.urlparse(url).query
qsl = urlparse.parse_qsl(qs)
```